# Brainf*ck Loop Problem

Tags: code-golf, tips, brainfuck

I have a problem for a cyber club that asks you to print:

```
ZYXWVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA@?>=<;:9876543210/.-,+*)('&%$#"!
```

Using Brainf**k in 29 bytes or less without using the ',' character.

I have a working code:

```
++++++++++[>++++++>+++++++++<<-]>-->.<[>-.<-]
```

However my loop is too long, sending me 16 bytes over the limit.

Is there a more efficient way to set the second and third cell to 58 and 90 so I can run my second loop? Or is there a better way to do this all together that I am just not seeing?

Comment: As for your question, while it only saves four bytes, it's actually better to generate *59* and *90* and change the `-.` to `.-`, dropping the `>.<`.

Comment: I got `+[--->++<]>++++[.-]` for 19 bytes but it prints the control chars as well...

Comment: @MartinEnder Yeah sorry about that, I saw your comment on the other post and found this group which seemed much more appropriate, I will delete the one on SO since it didn't generate many answers.

Comment: I'm honestly curious what this "cyber club" is, because boy they must have some really good golfers!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

### <s>27</s> 24 bytes

```
++[<++[++<]>>>+]<[-<-.>]
```

<s>Spent a whole day basically writing up a brute forcer and watching the results come in. Now I can get back to doing some actual work...</s> Another day of brute forcing later...

[Try it online!](http://brainfuck.tryitonline.net/#code=KytbPCsrWysrPF0-Pj4rXTxbLTwtLj5d&input=)

The component `++[<++[++<]>>>+]` initialises the tape to

```
[130, 0, 0, 0, 91, 59, 0]
                       ^
```

which is just perfect for what we need!

Comment: Wizardry. (∩｀-´)⊃━☆ﾟ.*･｡ﾟ

Comment: @primo To be fair I have no idea what's going on structure-wise in the first half, and I think the fact that you're able to come up with your own algorithms/techniques is amazing :)

Comment: Tape at the end of each loop: http://codepad.org/ZoJUlQ8M. It's not at all intuitive that it would terminate at the values that it does, or even at all ;)

Comment: An alternative 24: `+[[>++<<]>->+>+]<[-<-.>]`

Answer (score 15):

## 30 bytes

```
-<-[>+>-[---<]>]>++>+[---<.->]
```

[Try it online!](http://brainfuck.tryitonline.net/#code=LTwtWz4rPi1bLS0tPF0-XT4rKz4rWy0tLTwuLT5d&input=)

*85* and *171* are fairly easy to generate in brainfuck (modular inverses of *3* and *-3*). *85* is pretty close to *90*, and *171* is pretty close to *177* (*59·3*), which is used here. With a bit of hackery, I'm able to produce *88* and *176* instead.

Still one byte short of the target, though.

**Other suggestions**

In general, it's shorter to iterate over a list, multiplying by a constant, rather than the other way. This is especially true for 3 or more values. For example, this:

```
++++++++++[>++++++>+++++++++<<-]
```

can be written as:

```
+>++++[+++++[>++++++++++<-]<]>
```

There were only two inner values, so it's not much of an improvement in this case. In fact, just refactoring is one byte shorter:

```
+++++[>++++++[>++>+++<<-]<-]>
```

Multiplying *30* by *2* and *3*, rather than *10* by *6* and *9*. With Martin Büttner's suggestion, this is already down to *38* bytes, without much change to the original:

```
+++++[>++++++[>++>+++<<-]<-]>>-[>.-<-]
```

Comment: I never would have thought about multiplying up the 58 and iterating by a larger number, that's much more efficient.

Answer (score 4):

## 34 bytes

Saved you 11 bytes, but still 5 bytes too long...

```
+[--->++<]>++++<+[--------->.-<]>.
```

I've spent hours already, hopefully someone can improve on this.